# WCF data restrictions

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, xsd

**Is there still no way to inform the consuming client of data restrictions?**

This question is definitely a duplicate of others that were never answered or are at least 5 years old with no viable solution. The links have aged out or aren't helpful or refer to .Net 3.x and there wasn't anything we could do back then.

To be clear, this has NOTHING to do with validation by the service...please don't go there. This is only about the client being made aware of the restrictions through **auto-generated WSDL / XSD**.

Given the following WCF Service, with StringLength, Range, and DefaultValue specified....

VB version:

```
<ServiceContract([Namespace]:="example.com")>
Public Interface IWCF_Service
    <OperationContract()>
    Function Test1(Value As Something) As String

    Class Something
        <StringLength(50), DefaultValue("Whatever")>
        Public Property Thing1 As String = "Whatever"

        <Range(5, 50), DefaultValue(10), Required>
        Public Property Thing2 As Int32 = 10
    End Class
End Interface
```

C# version:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "example.com")]
public interface IWCF_Service
{
    [OperationContract()]
    string Test1(Something Value);

    public class Something
    {
        [StringLength(50), DefaultValue("Whatever")]
        public string Thing1 { get; set; }

        [Range(5, 50), DefaultValue(10), Required()]
        public Int32 Thing2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

... the generated XSD is missing the defaults and restrictions and Thing2 should be `minOccurs="1"` because it's Required:

```
<xs:complexType name="IWCF_Service.Something">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Thing1" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Thing2" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This is what I'd be expecting (or similar):

```
<xs:complexType name="IWCF_Service.Something">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Thing1" nillable="true" default="Whatever">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="50" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Thing2" default="10">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="5" />
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="50" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: why do you say "This is what I'd be expecting (or similar):" which one is the VB output and the C# output?

Comment: @Chillzy The C# / VB code is the input. The auto-generated WSDL / XSD is the output we're not getting.

Comment: I got that. The first output is the VB code output and the second is the C# output?

Comment: @Chillzy Both the VB and C# produce the very short XSD above.  The longer XSD is what I wish they'd produce.

Answer (score -1):

for me i do this by making an aditional class that has to var

```
status as short 
const SUCCESS as short= 1
const FAILED as short= 0
msg as string
```

and a function name invoke that returns an object of this class , all my service calls are redirected to this function , a constant for the res to check if the wanted function has been applied , if not i act based on the message

```
dim Result=//wcf call
if Result.status=SUCCSES then
//do something
else 
msgbox(Result.msg)
end if
```

Comment: I don't know what question you're answering but it isn't this one.